# WPF InnerShadow Design Issue

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, 3d, border

I have problem with creating `3D` like effects using `Border` element. I have written following markup. But that doesn't generate proper `3D effect` as like screenshot at following URL.

Screenshots image [URL](http://imm.io/11j2M):

```
<Window x:Class="MainWindow"  
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation" 
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml" Title="MainWindow" 
    Height="400" Width="225" WindowStyle="None" Topmost="True" 
    AllowsTransparency="True" Background="Transparent">

<Border x:Name="border" Margin="10" CornerRadius="10,10,10,10" BorderBrush="#111111" BorderThickness="0" Background="#111111">
    <Border.Effect>
        <DropShadowEffect ShadowDepth="0" Direction="0" BlurRadius="15" Color="Black" Opacity="1"/>
    </Border.Effect>
    <Border x:Name="border1" Margin="5" CornerRadius="{Binding CornerRadius, ElementName=border}">
        <Border.Background>
            <LinearGradientBrush StartPoint="0,0" EndPoint="0,1" >
                <GradientStop Color="#FF373737" Offset="0"/>
                <GradientStop Color="#FF222222" Offset="0.75"/>
                <GradientStop Color="#FF373737" Offset="1"/>
            </LinearGradientBrush>
        </Border.Background>
        <Border.Effect>
            <DropShadowEffect ShadowDepth="0" Direction="0" BlurRadius="10" Color="White" Opacity="1"/>
        </Border.Effect>
    </Border>
</Border>
</Window>
```

Comment: In provided screenshot Left side image is design assets and right side image that I have generated using markup.